# Delete all entries that have a certain field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have a database table that has 4 fields. It is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE meta (
      meta_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      object_id bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
      meta_key varchar(255) default NULL,
      meta_value longtext,
      PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
      KEY `object_id` (`object_id`),
      KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
    )
```

How can I delete all entries from this table, that have a certain `meta_key`, for eg. `foo` ?

Comment: Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DELETE FROM meta WHERE meta_key = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from meta where meta_key='foo'
```

Am i missing something??

Answer (score 1):

the query would be:

```
DELETE FROM meta WHERE meta_key = "foo";
```